# Find all combinations with 4 numbers,c#

Tags: c#, combinations, combinatorics

I have 4 numbers, and need to find all the combinations with 2 digits..

I tried to do this with 2 for loops, unfortunately dosent success..

This is my code, in the code 'small time' is an array of 4 numbers, each number has only 1 digit

```
        int[] smallTime = new int[4];
        int i = 0;
        smallTime[0]=2;
        smallTime[1]=9;
        smallTime[2]=3;
        smallTime[3]=2;
        String st = "";
        for (; i < smallTime.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < smallTime.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == i)
                    j++;
                if (j >= smallTime.Length)
                    break;
                st += smallTime[i].ToString() + smallTime[j].ToString() + ",";
            }
        }
```

with this array the result needs to be: "29,23,22,93,92,32"

Comment: give as an example please with normal numbers !

Comment: @mybirthname edit and add an example..

Comment: why 39 is not a combination ?

Comment: every combination only one time..93 and 39 is the same..

Comment: Please explain in what sense the code doesn’t succeed. (I guess you want to start with `j=i+1`, but it’s not clear to me what exactly you want to get.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are starting `j` from `1` you are skipping some combinations like i = 1, j = 0 and i = 2, j = 0. etc. Instead try skipping the current step if `i` and `j` are equal.

```
for (int i =0; i < smallTime.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < smallTime.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j == i)
            continue;

        st += smallTime[i].ToString() + smallTime[j].ToString() + ",";
     }
}
```

**Edit:** According to your update `j` should start from `i+1`

```
for (int i = 0; i < smallTime.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < smallTime.Length; j++)
    {
        st += smallTime[i].ToString() + smallTime[j].ToString() + ",";
    }
}
```